# Most pythonic way to convert a string to a octal number

Tags: python, python-2.6

I am looking to change permissions on a file with the file mask stored in a configuration file. Since os.chmod() requires an octal number, I need to convert a string to an octal number. For example:

```
'000' ==> 0000 (or 0o000 for you python 3 folks)
'644' ==> 0644 (or 0o644)
'777' ==> 0777 (or 0o777)
```

After an obvious first attempt of creating every octal number from 0000 to 0777 and putting it in a dictionary lining it up with the string version, I came up with the following:

```
def new_oct(octal_string):

    if re.match('^[0-7]+$', octal_string) is None:
        raise SyntaxError(octal_string)

    power = 0
    base_ten_sum = 0

    for digit_string in octal_string[::-1]:
        base_ten_digit_value = int(digit_string) * (8 ** power)
        base_ten_sum += base_ten_digit_value
        power += 1

    return oct(base_ten_sum)
```

Is there a simpler way to do this?

Comment: Don't confuse octal literal notation with the integer *value*; `0o644` is still 420 decimal. So is `0x1a4`, even though that uses hexadecimal notation. Python still stores 420 for either, you just spelled it differently to the interpreter. Once read, Python doesn't *store* it as octal, or hexadecimal.

Comment: The octal notation just makes it *easier* to read the value as then the digits neatly line up with the permissions. `420` doesn't easily tell the reader what the world, group and user permissions are. `os.chmod` doesn't *require* an octal number. It requires an integer, but writing it as octal just makes reading it back easier for *humans*.

Comment: I did understand that 0o644 in base 8 notation is the same number as 420 in base 10 notation. And for your second comment, readability was the whole point of the question. But, I did not through think the os.chmod() usage thoroughly enough, I didn't realize that the os.chmod() method didn't require a integer in octal format. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Have you just tried specifying base 8 to `int`:

```
num = int(your_str, 8)
```

Example:

```
s = '644'
i = int(s, 8) # 420 decimal
print i == 0644 # True #Python 2.x
```

For Python 3.x do

```
. . .
print(i == 0o644)
```

Comment: I cannot print `print(i == 0644)` in python3 @Jon Clements♦

Comment: @alper indeed... because: *leading zeros in decimal integer literals are not permitted; use an 0o prefix for octal integers* - so it should be `print(i == 0o644)`

Comment: Note to readers - this actually does NOT convert a string to an octal. `int(s, 8)` converts an octal string to its equivalent decimal form.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the soluation:

Turn octal string "777" to decimal number 511

```
dec_num = int(oct_string, 8) # "777" -> 511
```

you worry about the os.chmod()? Let's try!

```
os.chmod("file", 511)  # it works! -rwxrwxrwx.
os.chmod("file", 0777) # it works! -rwxrwxrwx.
os.chmod("file", int("2777",8)) # it works! -rwxrwsrwx. the number is 1535!
```

it proves that the chmod `can accept decimal` and `decimal can used as octal` in python !

---

it is enough for the octal, because if you try

```
print dec_num == 0777 # True
```

Then get the decimal number 511 translate to octal `string` "0777"

```
oct_num = oct(dec_num)  # 511 -> "0777" , it is string again.
```

Pay attention there is no number 0777 but only oct string "0777" or  dec num
in the python if you write number 0777, it auto translate 0777 to 511, in the process there is no 0777 number exist.

summary

```
dec_num = int(oct_string, 8)
oct_num = oct(int(oct_string,8))

print dec_num         # 511
print dec_num == 0777 # True ! It is actually 511, just like dec_num == 511
print oct_num         # 0777
print oct_num == 0777 # Flase! Because it is a string!
```

Comment: In Python 3 you have to use 0o777 rather than 0777. 0o777 works in Python 2 as well though.